# bcp append files using command

Tags: batch-file, command, bcp

I cannot append the files together using bcp command. I am getting one file and changing the name of it to todays date, every half hour a file comes in which needs appending to the renamed txt which has the date stamp in the file. once appended that file is move to another folder.

This occurs everyday moving the old txt into another folder and starting the process again. I can't manage to get this into one command script so I can put it into two batch files.

The first renames the file and clears out any old files from two locations, one is yesterdays file and the other is an archive folder for anything over 100 days (days doesn't matter as I am in testing at the moment):

```
rename C:\Testing\WithRCD\data_list201 CM_Exclusions_%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%.txt

forfiles /p c:\Testing\WithRCD\ /m *.txt /d -1 /c "cmd /c move @FILE c:\Testing\WithRCD\Archive\"

forfiles /p "c:\Testing\WithRCD\Archive\" /m *.* /d -100 /c "cmd /c Del c:\Testing\WithRCD\Archive\"
```

This seems to work but when trying to append the file together they will not, I am trying to use the following code:

```
copy /Y/V/DS data_list201+CM_Exclusions_%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%.txt
```

or even

```
copy data_list201+CM_Exclusions_%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%.txt TempFile.txt

DEL CM_Exclusions_%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%.txt

REN TempFile.txt CM_Exclusions_%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%.txt
```

but nothing I have tried is working.

Comment: What has this got to do with `bcp`?

Comment: You haven't told **why** it doesn't work. Are you getting error messages? What are they?

Comment: Hi - I am new at this so please be nice :-)

Comment: What is "not nice" about my comments?

Comment: It says 1 file copied - no errors but when I open up the txt the information from one file does move into the one which I want to use as the master txt.

Comment: This one   - I thought that this code is bcp....sorry if I was wrong...lol
 
What has this got to do with bcp? – DavidPostill 15 hours ago